# Uppercase to Dash utility works except when string starts with

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type utility **DashUppercase** that converts any uppercase characters in a string to a `-` followed by the lower case equivalent. It is typed as follows:

```
type LowerAlpha = "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g" | "h" | "i" | "j" | "k" | "l" | "m" | "n" | "o" | "p" | "q" | "r" | "s" | "t" | "u" | "v" | "w" | "x" | "y" | "z";
type UpperAlpha = Uppercase<LowerAlpha>;

type Replace<S extends string, W extends string, P extends string> =
  S extends '' ? '' : W extends '' ? S :
  S extends `${infer F}${W}${infer E}` ? `${F}${P}${E}` : S

type DashUppercase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer START}${UpperAlpha}${infer REST}`
  ? DashUppercase<`${START}-${Uncapitalize<Replace<S, START, "">>}`>
  : S;
```

> The **Replace** utility simple allows me to extract the START string so I can *un*-capitalize the remaining.

It does exactly what it's intended to when the first character is **not** a capital letter but when it the string literal passed in starts with a capital letter it just spins:

[image: working and not working images]

I did try and address this by creating a condition on the length of `START`:

```
export type StringLength<S extends string, A extends any[] = []> = S extends '' 
  ? A['length'] 
  : S extends `${infer First}${infer Rest}` ? StringLength<Rest, [First, ...A]> : never

export type DashUppercase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer START}${UpperAlpha}${infer REST}`
  ? StringLength<START> extends 0
    ? DashUppercase<`${Uncapitalize<S>}`>
    : DashUppercase<`${START}-${Uncapitalize<Replace<S, START, "">>}`>
  : S;
```

Figured this would give me an easy opportunity to convert the capitalized `S` to an uncapitalized version before starting. Sadly, the results are the same. Can anyone help me find what I'm doing wrong?

> [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3zyEN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are broadly two ways to use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to parse strings, and they both have caveats:

---

### CHARACTER-BY-CHARACTER

By far the simplest approach is to walk through a string character-by-character, like this:

```
type Something<T extends string> = 
   T extends `${infer C0}${infer R}` ? Combine<C0, Something<R>> : 
   BaseCase
```

where `C0` is the first character of the string and `R` is the rest.  When you have two `infer` placeholders next to each other, the compiler will infer a single character for the first one.  This is straightforward because you always know what will come out for `C0`.  And the main caveat is that recursion limits are shallow enough that something like this will only tend to work for strings of up to length 20 or so.  You can modify it slightly to roughly double or triple the maximum string length accepted, by grabbing two or three characters at once where possible.  For example:

```
type Something<T extends string> =
  T extends `${infer C0}${infer C1}${infer R}` ? Combine<C0, Combine<C1, Something<R>>> :
  T extends `${infer C0}${infer R}` ? Combine<C0, Something<R>> : 
  BaseCase
```

---

If we approach `DashUppercase` with this method, we get:

```
type _DU<T extends string> = T extends Lowercase<T> ? T : `-${Lowercase<T>}`;

type DashUppercase<T extends string> =
  T extends `${infer C0}${infer R}` ? `${_DU<C0>}${DashUppercase<R>}` :
  ""
```

which is pretty simple.  Note that instead of keeping a list of uppercase characters, I identify an uppercase character `T` as something that changes when you apply `Lowercase<T>` to it.   It works for your use cases (I think):

```
type A = DashUppercase<'oneTwoThree'> // "one-two-three"
type B = DashUppercase<'OneTwoThree'> // "-one-two-three"
type C = DashUppercase<'23Skidoo'> // "23-skidoo"
```

but, as I said, long-ish strings cause recursion warnings:

```
type Oops = 
  DashUppercase<'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'> // error, too long, excessively deep
```

If I change it to two-by-two, you get:

```
type DashUppercase<T extends string> =
  T extends `${infer C0}${infer C1}${infer R}` ? 
    `${_DU<C0>}${_DU<C1>}${DashUppercase<R>}` :
  T extends `${infer C0}${infer R}` ? `${_DU<C0>}${DashUppercase<R>}` :
  ""

type Okay = DashUppercase<'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'> // okay now

type Oops = 
  DashUppercase<'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw'> // too long
```

which may or may not be long enough for your use case.

---

### DELIMITER-SPLITTING

The other approach, which is what you're trying to do, is to split the string at delimiters.  This probably has a section that looks like `` T extends `${infer F}${D}${infer R}` `` in it, where `F` is the first part of the string, `D` is some delimiter or union of delimiters, and `R` is the rest of the string.  The appeal of this is that, assuming your input string has few delimiters in it, you will not run into recursion limits.  The major drawback is that it's complicated and hard to know what will come out for `F` and `R`.

The compiler will tend to infer unions here if there are multiple candidates; nothing prevents `F` from containing `D`.  This is what is biting you in your definition.  So you will want to eliminate from `F` anything which contains a `D` itself, and then you need to infer the rest of the string a second time if you need to identify the delimiter (if `D` is a union and you care which member matched).

[In this GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336#issuecomment-686723087) I wrote a general `Break<T, D>` utility that takes a string `T` and splits it into a tuple of the form `[F, R]` where `F` is the longest prefix not containing `D`, and `R` is the rest of the string.  It looks like this:

```
type Break<T extends string, D extends string> = (
  string extends T ? [string, string] : (
    T extends `${infer F}${D}${infer R}` ? (
      F extends `${infer X}${D}${infer Y}` ? never : (
        T extends `${F}${infer R}` ? [F, R] : never
      )
    ) : [T, ""]
  )
);
```

Yuck!  But it does seem to work.

---

Armed with that, we can write `DashUppercase` like this:

```
type DashUppercase<T extends string> =
  Break<T, UpperAlpha> extends [infer L, infer R] ?
  L extends string ? R extends `${infer U}${infer RR}` ?
  `${L}-${Lowercase<U>}${DashUppercase<RR>}` : L :
  never : never;
```

So we `Break` `T` by the `UpperAlpha` delimiter set (which we do need; another point against this method, in my opinion).  The returned `L` contains no uppercase characters, so we can always return that at the beginnning of the string.  `R` either starts with an uppercase character, which we can peel off and transform, or it is empty.

This now works for all the tests from before, including the long ones:

```
type A = DashUppercase<'oneTwoThree'> // "one-two-three"
type B = DashUppercase<'OneTwoThree'> // "-one-two-three"
type C = DashUppercase<'23Skidoo'> // "23-skidoo"
type Okay = DashUppercase<'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'> // okay now
type Okay2 = 
  DashUppercase<'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw'> // also okay
```

Of course if you end up having lots of uppercase characters, then this will hit recursion limits, and even sooner than before because of the multiple conditional checks in `Break`:

```
type Oops = DashUppercase<'ABCDEFGHIJKL'> // too long
```

You *might* be able to avoid this limit by switching back and forth between searching for uppercase characters and searching for non-uppercase characters, but at this point I'd rather run screaming than try to write that.  Especially because the list of "non-uppercase characters" is quite long.

---

So there you go.  You can either parse characters individually or in small groups and get straightforward definitions that only work for fairly short strings, or search for delimiters and get convoluted and complicated definitions that work for longer strings.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkqJLAsgMIAWIATgEICeN9AogB7gwbIHHEALkxjIAygHtIg6gEtgAcwA8AFSQQOgiMAAmUJFEF15CgHxIAvEQHE1Grbv0ADACS55AMwh0klAAwAvm6e3kgASgFOSAD8vlIARvIQSv4ANEiS0nKKSmGm5gBcSAwgUBCUpRDWQiJUCUmq6praegZGJukAqk0OrYbGiuYWSK64KgEFbp2R1UjCosWVFWWWSABEbAByACJrs-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-DCJkFjSMtShKI-ajvwHGD4QAZjEABrWQdAkCRMITbCJLHKAZLkiQ+JeOiJBgfRhgg4Td1Ey5rggDwFDkAArKSMDAYBdIARzoQwAFcADduw4JgsEUxNvDoCQ6HSQR5KQDB4IUdINEQKAoFkdyIAwJgkBuCAYALfMwSLcgoQrcsEVRaskCffd5TtY9ZRJTsexEuchyq0cJ1wKc6sHJcVzIpBDK-Yy52qw98SGGV2wvVV6RVRV6SZca73Zd1cFKl8aSWhlX1wHqaIHX8on-U9RoVK9qVm8J71iR96xSPx1s2tqdqlGU1j2YqwIMqjeuguDGOQ4jWKU9ZOIIiQiN44qKLeoSPtohiIEQn6WL87COO5LjgZ4kjioEiHILasTJPU+TEfWFS1Nk+StIWOipJAFLsaMz7TJuCzrNs+ynJcwQPK8nyiYkamUoc7tip0vTBJxvrYMZ8zLNkGy7IcmBnLczzvKwKXmdl1mFaVznPKJ0KJHCyLMsIaxwVy8QeFkQRtiS2QwFRMMFlaugQIwGBaFTNYkAAH3WeJvb9tZ4ED9YdFDtZbl99YPAjhQI+oCPZAjqyI6kiOMAjsAI+ACPNOjtYYAjxyI7oCOoAjwQI9ciP3Ij7sI44COmAjrA1mXJ3kCMt2PZAVZ6b3F2e9oUxlzBtCQCksrnSPKLuoG-QWwJYYAAoZSXheqtiABtJf0iXgBdKUkDXgCzwPQ7byQAAxGlthvNUzpPmUbGvzfLyvgANO+H9CABNJ+3JEo+CKKfM+NgDoLVviddUO9r7pDCEfIoQDvAvwEAASjQeg4+28VDpCegfGUmCbDoLHp3bq70tr9XPIvWew0AIMAnlPPBDperDxAOYGhSBt5Xg7OkK8iCYgyg7JvDesQwjvxOtMGBsCZSjA7AEZqLtoKdBupQu690igiL2jYFBICSAQGAWPF6YsB6iVwnDZi6EiY4RRkDEGGNyHgwoZDKhsEYaWN+jY5GeF7Ho1uJjUxUNRISWkmTBSbE1gkwJppYW-MgluJgurGWcs2aKw5lzVWvN4mCziTTeECTcbJJZvLdmytuZq1jNLEpaSdZcyJpgKAhs+Y006paEW+kXHi0+iBBglBthsGvgAcQABIAEkUAAGkOz6zChFRQptiAggCEAA)

Comment: they need to start giving out Nobel prizes for Typescript contributions and I'm assuming you'll be the first winner!

Comment: the one thing that would be cool -- but I guess probably not possible -- is to switch to a wider "string" type at the point that recursion hits its limit.

Answer (score 1):

Following part:

```js
S extends `${infer START}${UpperAlpha}${infer REST}`
```

Does not behave as you expected.

If you modify your function for testing:

```js
export type DashUppercase<S extends string> =
  S extends `${infer START}${UpperAlpha}${infer REST}`
    ? START
    : S;
```

You'll see very strange results:

```js
type T1 = DashUppercase<"Two">; // ""
type T2 = DashUppercase<"TwoThree">; // ""
type T3 = DashUppercase<"oneTwoThree">; // "one"
type T4 = DashUppercase<"oneTwoThreeFour">; // "oneTwoThree" | "one"
type X = DashUppercase<"OneTwoThree">; // "" | "One"
```

When same capital letter repeats multiple times, it works as expected. But when there are different letters involved, results are returned as array, for each capital letter separately (in case of `type X` for `"O"` you get `""` and for `"T"` you get `"One"`, so `"" | "One"`.

Full playground link is here: https://tsplay.dev/wXkK1W

However, I am not sure how to get around this problem. :(

Comment: strange though that it works when first character is not uppercase

Comment: It's working only by accident, because in you test case `"oneTwoThree"` two capital letters where the same `T`. If you would try `"twoThreeFour"`, code would break down.

Comment: ahh yes i see the pattern now